# Is it possible to modify a stored sharedprefrences value?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I added a sharedpreferences to store data. When I set for the first time the users's names and passwords and the max limit the app stores them in the sharedpreferences. If i quit the app and re-open it, I can get my data back, but if I try to modify the max limit, quit the app and re-open it, it's like if I don't have any data in my sharedpreferences.

So the question is, is it possible to modify a stored sharedpreferences value? and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you save your changes using `apply()`.

For example:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("maxlimit", 1000);
editor.apply();
```